# How do I do a LIKE % query in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to find some items that contain a certain string. If I do:

```
MyModel.where("description LIKE ?",keyword)
```

it will generate a query for an exact match. I would like to make it generate a `LIKE %keyword%` query. How can I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
like_keyword = "%#{keyword}%"    
MyModel.where("description LIKE ?", like_keyword)
```

Comment: It's not working. The generated query ends like this:  `LIKE '%'keyword'%'` and it throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for this. Am doing a search using a `LIKE` operator as well and was stumped. I'm defining my `like keyword` ahead of time as well and then doing: `collection = Model.where("attribute like ?", "% #{keyword} %")`

Answer (score 11):

```
MyModel.where("description LIKE (?)", "%#{keyword}%")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.where("name LIKE 'SH%'")
```

It will fetch all the name whose starting with only SH. It will work 100%.
eg. SH123,SH2343

Comment: Bailing this one out of -1 territory.  If the name parameter is not submitted by the user, this is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ILIKE for this

```
MyModel.where("description ILIKE (?)", "%#{keyword}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL it will be

```
MyModel.where("description ILIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
```